# Safely converting from struct sockaddr to struct sockaddr_storage

Tags: c, pointers, tcp, network-programming, ipv6

I have a function which takes in "struct sockaddr *" as a parameter (let's call this input_address), and then I need to operate on that address, which may be a sockaddr_in or sockaddr_in6, since I support both IPv4 and IPv6.

I'm getting some memory corruption and trying to track it down to it's source, and in the process found some code that seems suspect, so I would like to validate if this is the right way to do things.

```
struct sockaddr_storage *input_address_storage = (struct sockaddr_storage *) input_address;
struct sockaddr_storage result = [UtilityClass performSomeOperation: *input_address_storage];
```

At first I thought the cast in the first line was safe, but then in the second line I need to dereference that pointer, which seems like it may be wrong. The reason I am concerned is that it may end up copying memory that is beyond where the original structure is (since sockaddr_in is shorter than sockaddr_in6). I am not sure if this could cause a memory corruption (my guess is no), but nevertheless this code gives me a bad feeling.

I can't change the fact my function takes a "struct sockaddr *", so it seems like it would be difficult to work around this type of code, and yet I want to avoid copying from a memory location where I shouldn't be.

If anyone can validate whether what I am doing is wrong, and the best way to fix this, I'd appreciate it.

EDIT: An admin had changed my C tag for C# for some reason. The code I gave is primarily C, with one function call from objective C that doesn't really matter. That call could have been C.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that you are converting an existing `struct sockaddr*` into a `struct sockaddr_storage*`. Imagine what happens if the original was a ``struct sockaddr_in`. Since`sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) < sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage)`, the memory-sanitizer complains of unbound memory reference.

`struct sockaddr_storage` is essentially a [container](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html) to contain either your `struct sockaddr_in` or `struct sockaddr_in6`.

Hence, it is useful when you want to pass in a `struct sockaddr*` object but want to allocate enough memory for both `sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr_in6`.

A good example is the [recvfrom(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/recvfrom) call:

```
ssize_t recvfrom(int socket, void *restrict buffer, size_t length,
                 int flags, struct sockaddr *restrict address,
                 socklen_t *restrict address_len);
```

Since `address` requires a `struct sockaddr*` object, we will construct a `struct sockaddr_storage` first, and pass it in:

```
struct sockaddr_storage address;
socklen_t address_length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage);
ssize_t ret = recvfrom(fd, buffer, buffer_length, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&address, &address_length);

if (address.ss_family == AF_INET) {
  DoIpv4Work((struct sockaddr_in*)&address, ...);
} else if (address.ss_family == AF_INET6) {
  DoIpv6Work((struct sockaddr_in6*)&address, ...);
}
```

The difference in your approach and mine is that I allocate a `struct sockaddr_storage` and then use it as `struct sockaddr`, but you do the **REVERSE**, and use a `struct sockaddr` and then use it as `struct sockaddr_storage`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What you said makes sense however it doesn't directly solve my problem, since my requirement is that I have a function which takes a "struct sockaddr * ", so I have have to do something like the reverse. So the question is, assuming I need to do the reverse, what is the proper way to do it.